# Prism MVVM Binding to User Control Dependency Property

Tags: xaml, mvvm, user-controls, prism, dependency-properties

I have a Universal app that I'm writing and I want to use Prism and Unity as my MVVM framework. Everything was going great until I got to a view where I have multiple instances of the same user control(a custom Watermark Textbox). For some reason, I haven't been able to find a good solution to my problem. I imagine I'm overlooking something and there is a straightforward answer.

Here's my source code(just the relevant portions). Some background, I had this working before implementing Prism. The Commands attached to the user controls are firing as expected but I can't figure out how to manipulate the control itself):

Any guidance on how to use user controls with Prism or binding to dependency properties with Prism would be great. Thanks.

My View

```
        <!-- I want to be able to set the watermark and also retrieve the text from my ViewModel -->
        <uc:WatermarkTextBox Width="250"
                             x:Name="FullName">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <iCore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="GotFocus">
                    <iCore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EntryFieldFocus}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FullName}"/>
                </iCore:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </uc:WatermarkTextBox>

        <!-- This one as well -->
        <uc:WatermarkTextBox Width="250"
                             x:Name="EmailAddress">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <iCore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="GotFocus">
                    <iCore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EntryFieldFocus}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EmailAddress}" />
                </iCore:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>              
        </uc:WatermarkTextBox>
```

Comment: What do you want to manipulate on the control? From your question it's not clear what you want to achieve, making it hard to give you an accurate answer

Comment: @Tseng, apologies if I was unclear. I want to manipulate the Text on the WatermarkTextBox. The custom WatermarkTextBox is made up of just a normal Xaml Textbox. When the user navigates to the view, I want to show the Watermark Text(default text) and when they give focus to the control, I want to remove the watermark text so they can begin typing. Once they are finished entering in the fields, I need access to what they typed in each field.

Comment: The question was more, why you pass the textbox content to the command, when you can already bind it directly? Prism doesn't have a special way of binding, it's plain old MVVM + WPF Binding, Prism doesn't change the way bindings work. So what would be wrong with  `<uc:WatermarkTextBox Width="250" x:Name="FullName" Text={Binding ElementName=EmailAddress}" Watermark="{Binding ElementName=EmailAddressWatermark}">`?

Comment: When I've attempted to bind Dependency properties, I get the error: " Failed to assign to property %0", so I didn't know exactly how to go about binding to a dependency property.

Comment: You don't have a WatermarkTextBoxViewModel, do you?

Comment: I do have one, but I'm confused as to how I need to implement it. Binding straight to the views has not been a problem at all.

Comment: `WatermarkTextBoxViewModel`? A user control don't need a ViewModel. Infact, a control shouldn't have a ViewModel. ViewModels are for Views, not controls. From the naming of the Binded property it sounds more like a "UserViewModel" which prepares the data to be consumed by a `UserView`/`UserPage`. Any attempt to try to split Control logic between Conrol/CodeBehind and a ViewModel for that Control will ultimately fail.

Answer (score 0):

Going from your comments/error message ("Failed to assign to property %0") when attempting to bind the property directly, the Property you are trying to bind to isn't a dependency property.

Your `WatermarkTextBox` only implements a CLR Property, like this:

```cs
public class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox {
    public object Watermark { get; set; } 
}
```

This can't be used for databinding.

You need to implement it as Dependency Property, like

```cs
public class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox {
    public object Watermark
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(WatermarkProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Watermark", typeof(object), typeof(WatermarkTextbox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

This will allow to use `<uc:WatermarkTextBox Watermark={Binding watermarkText, Mode=TwoWay}` for example.

If you can't modify `WatermarkTextBox` (third-party closed source control), then you'll have to implement an [attached behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28980599/455493) and then bind your ViewModel Property to the attached behavior and assign the `Watermark` property from within it.

If you need TwoWay binding (which is unlikely in case of `Watermark` property, since it won't be changed from UI), you have to register an event handler (`KeyDown` in linked answer) to this specific event and pass the new value to the attached property

Except these two ways, there is no way to update a Control's CLR property without violating MVVM.